# Adding an element to an np array and then quicksorting? Or finding a way to insert it into place, python and np arrays

Tags: python, numpy, artificial-intelligence, depth-first-search

Hey so I'm writing an AI program that does a DFS of the solution tree. I've got the actual tree building part all down, now I'm just trying to figure out the best solution for building the array that holds my visited nodes to help speed up the process as a DFS for the problem that I'm trying to solve can take a huge amount of time.

Currently I have a state for each of my positions that holds 5 different variables, 4 of them being positions and a fifth being some other element I'm keeping track of. I'm creating an Nx5 np array that will hold all of my states that I've already visited. I'll be using the array to check if the current state that I'm at in my tree has been visited already. I want this to be as efficient as possible and so I've been looking at a couple ways to solve it. One would be just appending the current state to that array and then running a quicksort, although that seems a little excessive.

I should also mention I'm trying to sort by the 1st element in the 5 variables, it is an x coordinate for one of my pieces on the board. So I basically want my first column, the Nx1 column to be sorted. I feel like it would be easier to just insert into the list into a sorted position, so if my x value is 4 it would go through the sorted array until it hits the place where the array is holding values of 4, and then just insert it there as this would be a linear time algorithm.

My question is how would I actually implement an insertion of that kind in numpy? The insert function lets you insert into a specific index, but what if I don't know the index of which the 4s in the first column of my array start in this case? Is there a way to find this in numpy?

Basically how do I find the index of the first element in the first column that is containing the value x in a 2-D np array.

Edit : I've found that the line in the code below will return the row which first contains my value x, but now I just need to figure out how to insert at this index, I'm not quite sure how to find the index of this row.

```
#Holds the stack of the states I'm in
myStack
#Holds all of the list of the visited states so far
visited
#Is the current state that we are in of the board
state

#I have found that this will return the first instance of a row where the number I'm looking for is at

array = visited[np.where(visited[:, 0] == x)][0]

#If I try to run this line it doesn't return the index even though I thought it would, instead it gives me some weird tuple like this
#(array([0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 4], dtype=int32), array([0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 0], dtype=int32))
index = np.where(visited = array)
if state in visited[:, 0]:
    skip over this iteration
```

I think I'll just end up writing my own function that goes through the array rows and returns the index of the first one to match array = visited[np.where(visited[:, 0] == x)][0]

Comment: Can you edit the question and add some of the code you've written? Easier to understand code than read a few paragraphs about it.

Comment: If you use a queue to do the traversal, you don't need to keep track of everything that has been visited so far. You start by adding the root node, then visit it. Add the children to the queue. Pop the first child, and visit it, add it's children to the queue, etc. Keep the queue as lightweight as possible by tracking only the node IDs.

Comment: Yea a queue would make sense, but that would be doing a BFS. I'm trying to solve the problem using a DFS which would be the equivalent of making a stack instead of a queue. I've already solved it using a queue which is much easier, and now I'm just trying to figure out how to solve it using a DFS manner instead

Comment: @razdi There is a lot of code that is part of it, I can try adding some of the parts that would make sense, to preface, the game is a cat and mouse game where the cat has to eat the mouse before it eats all of the pieces of cheese on the board. I'll see what I can put in to try to make the question more clear

Comment: You can do depth-first with a queue as well, just use a last-in first out rather than first-in first out queue. Start at the root, add the children. Pop the last child, visit it and add it`s children; repeat.

Comment: @Benjamin oh ok! I might try doing it like that then if this doesn't work out, thanks a lot for the advice!

Comment: `np.searchsorted` can be used to find where to insert a new value into a sorted array.  Presumably that value could be used with `np.insert`.  But be ware that `insert` is not very efficient.  It makes a whole new array with each call.  List insert  works with references (pointers) and works in place, so is more efficient.